# Elasticsearch : How to explain the score of a multi index query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has an [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) that you can use to understand why a particular document matches with a query and its score. However, unlike the search API, this API only accepts a single index. The score generated will be specific to that index.

If my search API is running across multiple indices, I would like to understand the scoring across multiple indices as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index Data for `index1`:**

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "cost":"55",
    "discount":"20"
}
{
    "name":"Mark",
    "cost":"5",
    "discount":"2"
}
```

**Index Data for `index2`:**

```
{
    "name":"Mark",
    "cost":"5",
    "discount":"2"
}
{
    "name":"Swiss",
    "cost":"5",
    "discount":"2"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
GET /index1,index2/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "mark"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

**In the search result, you will find the explanation for both indexes seperately.**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[index1][0]",
        "_node": "wFPbanyvSQStSEcy46D_HQ",
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Mark",
          "cost": "5",
          "discount": "2"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.6931471,
          "description": "weight(name:mark in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.6931471,
              "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 2.2,
                  "description": "boost",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.6931472,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.45454544,
                  "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "dl, length of field",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[index2][0]",
        "_node": "wFPbanyvSQStSEcy46D_HQ",
        "_index": "index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Mark",
          "cost": "5",
          "discount": "2"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.6931471,
          "description": "weight(name:mark in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.6931471,
              "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 2.2,
                  "description": "boost",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.6931472,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.45454544,
                  "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "dl, length of field",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I saw the explain API and didn't realize explain can also work this way.
I wonder why there is a separate explain API if the search API already accepts an explain flag.